# How To Resolve Azure Function `Stream Too Long` Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am currently working on syncing data from Azure Blob Storage to the GCP bucket. We want this sync action to happen as soon as the blob gets populated.

I have decided on BlobTriggered Azure Function which works as expected but once the file is considerably large (say 1.5GB?), things begin to fail. Initially, I thought this was because my code was not optimized.

After all sorts of troubleshooting, I found that the function fails even by listening to the blob event alone. You will see below that I didn't do any processing of the blob, yet it failed.

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
      logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

        )
```

All I am doing is log the name and size of the blob but I got the errors below.

```
2021-11-11 15:49:38.937
Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected: tokboxlog/47189174/test-dir-three-ssalami/arrow-larg-two.avi', Id=2dea7d82-eaa3-484f-a47a-c386aca5d926)
Information
2021-11-11 15:49:38.941
Trigger Details: MessageId: 39e440c1-a5ef-4ff4-b2ba-010fa2373759, DequeueCount: 2, InsertionTime: 2021-11-11T15:37:06.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2021-11-09T13:27:44.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2021-11-09T13:27:44.000+00:00
Information
2021-11-11 15:49:53.434
python exited with code 137
Error
2021-11-11 15:49:53.436
Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Failed, Id=2dea7d82-eaa3-484f-a47a-c386aca5d926, Duration=134084ms)
Error
2021-11-11 15:49:54.121
python exited with code 137
```

```
2021-11-11 15:46:29.918
Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Reason='New blob detected: Stream was too long.', Id=3af25993-ffb5-43b7-83ed-ae5d0448757f)
Information
2021-11-11 15:46:29.919
Trigger Details: MessageId: a7c095ba-5879-4a57-a267-8a5debfd935f, DequeueCount: 5, InsertionTime: 2021-11-11T15:37:06.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2021-11-09T13:26:30.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2021-11-09T13:26:30.000+00:00
Information
2021-11-11 15:46:30.159
Stream was too long.
Error
2021-11-11 15:46:30.160
Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger1' (Failed, Id=3af25993-ffb5-43b7-83ed-ae5d0448757f, Duration=91987ms)
Error
2021-11-11 15:46:30.161
Stream was too long.
```

And this is failing regardless of SKU. Fails on EP3, P2V2.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work for lage files as your function will receive the entire stream and will try to allocate it in memory. You'll need to read the content in chunks inside your function code, or have a previous step which will split the large file into smaller ones

Comment: Hi @Thiago Custodio, that is what I suspected too. But how do I listen to the even without receiving the stream so that I can use Blobclient to chunk it.

Comment: you'll need to change and use Event Grid trigger

Comment: I am trying to decide capturing the event through Azure Event Grid and using this to trigger the function might help.